# Как закрыть Responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт плавного скролла по якорям. Нужно на разрешении меньше 767 отследить клик по якорю в меню, и свернуть меню. Помогите дописать скрипт.

```js
   $(".main-list").on("click", "a", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: top - 50 }, 2000);
    });
```

Тут я пытался сделать проверку, но делаю это неправильно. Я не могу понять, после какого события мне сворачивать меню.

```
     $(".main-list").on("click", "a", function(event) {

      $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if($(window).width() <= 767) {
          $('.page-header-contact').slideToggle();
        } 
        }).trigger('resize');

     });
```

Comment: $(".main-list").on("click", "a", function(event) {}) а внутри функции уже  делайте проверку if ($(window).width() > 767) {}. Если да, то тогда и сворачивайте, если нет... то что вам там нужно.
Или я не понял вопроса?

Comment: я обновил код, посмотрите пожалуйста, в чем там ошибка ? Меню закрывается, но зато ведет себя странно, может само открыться, я что-то упустил

Comment: я так понимаю, что первый скрипт, конфликтует со вторым, где я проверку делаю

Comment: Зачем вам $(window).on('resize', function(){})? 
у вас будет срабатывать событие при клике на меню, потом внутри вы должны проверять width() окна, и если да то тогда скрывать

Comment: я понял, подскажите тогда, как мне тригер на ресайз окна подцепить к проверки ? потому что, если ресайзить окно, меню пропадает

Comment: зачем? 
с помощью css просто его показывайте https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Потому что, если открыть адаптивное меню в браузере, а потом растянуть экран, меню не будет отоброжаться совсем, только после перезагрузки страницы, это плохо))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66768/discussion-between-oleksandr-and-denis-denis).

Comment: Александр спасибо, я уже разобрался, там после тогда как я сворачивал меню через slideToggle, добавлялся display: none инлайново, я сделал проверку и отмену, все работает как нужно. Спасибо вам за помощь, добрый вы человек )